# In which fragment method we need to consume weservice of long run

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In which method it will be appropriate to call the web service from an android fragment?

- *oncreateView()* or
- *oncreate()* or
- *onViewCreated()*

Comment: hey checks these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852917/android-fragment-which-life-cycle-method-to-use-for-web-service-call 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333092/right-approach-to-call-web-serviceapi-from-fragment-class

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282126/web-service-calls-in-fragment-class


and your requirement or problem needs more details.

Comment: None, efficient implementation will be by involving appropriate Design Patterns into your code, particularly Observer pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onStart()` method

- Use an `Async Task` call in the `onStart()` mentod  and run a
  background thread
- In the AsyncTask use `doInBackground()` to run the methods that take
  longer time to execute
- Update the UI thread in `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()`,
  `onProgressUpdate()`

---

[Async task Example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) :

```
public class FrgLatein extends Fragment {
    //New-Instance
    public static FrgLatein newInstance(){
        Log.d("FrgLatein", "newInstance");
        FrgLatein fragment = new FrgLatein();
        return  fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("FrgLatein", "onCreateView");
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_latein, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("FrgLatein", "onActivityCreated");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d("FrgLatein", "onStart");
        super.onStart();
        new LongOperation().execute("");

    }

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             // Do the Web service long run here
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          // Do the UI-task here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          // Do the UI-task here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
          // Do the UI-task here which has to be done during backgroung tasks are running like a downloading process
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Boldness is not required. use it where it is required not all the time. you are always using boldness in your answers which is not actually required.

Comment: Still some text are bold. which not required. **Use Bold where it is required.**

Answer (score -1):

You can call the WebService at `onCreateView()` method of your fragment like this -

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment
{

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainFragment,container ,false);

    new GetWebService().execute();

    return view;
  }

  class GetWebService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
  {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
       super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
    {

       //Call Webservice here and return the result

       return "";  
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
       //Do something with result
    }
}
```